# Why not chosen select2 is being applied for selectlist with same data from ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, razor, jquery-chosen

I am extremely new bie for JQuery UI and especially when using the plugins.
I am setting select2 chosen for SelectList populated from MVC Controller as ViewBag.

I have the same SelectList data for multiple rows of HTML table. So, I want to apply chosen select2 for all rows containing SelectList ( operting on same ViewBag data ).

But I only see chosen select2 applied for VERY first SelectList placed at the first row of HTML table row. All other rows are not showing select2-chosen as applied.

Can I have the solution ?

Here 's the Code segment :

```
<table class="table table-hover">

        <tr>
            <th>@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProgramName)</th>
        </tr>
        @if( Model!=null )
        { 
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>

                    <td width="64%">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProgramName)</td>
                    <td width="15%">@Html.ListBox("SemesterList", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.SemesterList, new { @class = "chosen-select" })</td>                

                    <td class="warning">                    
                        @Html.ActionLink("Plan", "Plan", new { id = item.ProgramId }, new { @class = "btn btn-info btn-block" })

                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        var linkObj;
        var items = [];

        $("#SemesterList").select2
         ({
            placeholder: "Choose Semester..",
            maximumSelectionSize: 10,
            width: 150
        });    
    });
</script>
```

and the rednered output is

[image]

Regards
Usman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You assigned multiple of the same `Id` attribute to the dropdownlist. `Id` attribute should be unique, the browser will only render the first one. That's why you only got one correct result. You need to replace `Id` attribute by using `class` attribute, like below:

```
 $(".chosen-select").select2
   ({
        placeholder: "Choose Semester..",
        maximumSelectionSize: 10,
        width: 150
   });
```

Comment: No it didn't worked correctly! in this way, it is not applying at all to the dropdownlist and simple html based drop down list is being displayed..